# Help restore destroyed zfs snapshot

Tags: linux, data-recovery, zfs

Docker tricked me, after a sas backplane problem, the server had been booted without the zfs systems mounted, this caused docker to create a clean directory structure under /data/servers/fs (which is where my docker is configured to keep data).

When I had fixed the backplane problem, the system booted and all looked normal.
Except no docker containers. I investigated the directory, there were only the files from a "fresh" docker startup, so I mistakenly assumed that docker had wiped everything for no good reason.

I did not notice that the dataset was not mounted!!! So I thought to restore from a previous snapshot.

I did a recursive snapshot. (I hope this will save me!)

When I tried restoring the previous snapshot for the docker-fs set, it refused due to the newer snapshot.

I destroyed the new snapshot, only for the docker-fs set.

I restored the old snapshot.

Still no files..

It was at this point I knew I'd screwed up, zfs had politely refused to mount the dataset on a nonempty directory.

I cleared out the auto-created files from the mountpoint, and my.. too old snapshot was mounted just-fine.

I've not done anything else, so I hope there's a chance I might still restore to the new snapshot...

Here's the relevant portion of the history, my tank is called twig because I'm weird.

zpool history:

```
2022-11-26.15:46:50 zfs snapshot -r twig@full-2022-11-26-nodockerfs [user 0 (root) on delta:linux]
2022-11-26.15:47:54 [txg:39471260] destroy twig/servers/fs@full-2022-11-26-nodockerfs (671)  [on delta]
2022-11-26.15:47:56 ioctl destroy_snaps
    input:
        snaps:
            twig/servers/fs@full-2022-11-26-nodockerfs
 [user 0 (root) on delta:linux]
2022-11-26.15:47:56 zfs destroy twig/servers/fs@full-2022-11-26-nodockerfs [user 0 (root) on delta:linux]
2022-11-26.15:47:56 [txg:39471261] clone swap twig/servers/fs/%rollback (704) parent=fs [on delta]
2022-11-26.15:47:56 [txg:39471261] destroy twig/servers/fs/%rollback (704)  [on delta]
2022-11-26.15:48:03 ioctl rollback
    output:
        target: 'twig/servers/fs@2020-10-11-all'
 [user 0 (root) on delta:linux]
2022-11-26.15:48:03 zfs rollback twig/servers/fs@2020-10-11-all [user 0 (root) on delta:linux]
```

I have gone ahead and stopped docker and unmounted the dataset.. I really I'm not entirely screwed yet ^_^

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux. Please [take the tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how Unix & Linux works. Read [how to ask](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of your question. Then take a look to [the help center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to see if some _on-topic questions_ are already asked.